# How to assign value of variable in another variable

Tags: bash, sh

I have "INSTALLMODE=BASIC" key value pair defined in my config file. And, I am splitting these key value pairs and assigning them as below.

```
INSTALLMODE=BASIC
key=INSTALLMODE
x=`echo $key`
```

Now, I want to get value of $x as BASIC. How could I do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Or maybe `INSTALLMODE=BASIC; key="$INSTALLMODE"; x="$key"` (however convoluted it may be)?

Comment: Key should have keyname only, as I am using it for comparison at different place.
I need a new variable with value of keyname.

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicates, see the detailed discussion in [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: Fantastic. y="${!x}" worked.
Thanks Charles.